# How to delete a branch in the remote repository using EGIT?

Tags: eclipse, git, branch, egit

How to delete the remote branch itself in sourceforge with all files in it, using egit ?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Go to `Team > Remote > Push…` from the menu. Select your repository, and click `Next`. Under `Remote ref to delete…` select your branch and click `Add spec`. Then click `Finish`. This should delete the remote branch.

[image: how-to-delete-remote-branch-in-eclipse-egit]

Comment: thanks a lot ! it was there in front of me and I never saw it :D

Comment: I love me some straightforward and effective SO answer.

Comment: This will work for any git repository as long as deletes have not been disabled.

Comment: FYI, there appears to be no way to do this inside the 'Git' perspective; you can right lick on 'Remotes' and choose push but you actually save the delete `ref` mappings.

Answer (score 13):

(Update March 2012)

As [tukushan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149412/tukushan) mentions in the comment:

> In Egit 1.3.0, this only deletes the remote tracking branch in the local repository, not the remote branch.

As [Michael Mior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123695/michael-mior) details in [his (upvoted) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8625647/6309), you need to [push "nothing" to the remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/6309) : `git push origin :branch`, which from git1.7+ is better coded as `git push origin --delete branch`.

With Egit, see "[Delete Ref Specifications section](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Delete_Ref_Specifications)":

[image: Remote ref to delete in Egit]

---

(Original answer December 2011)

You can also check out the very latest release of EGit (1.2, released yesterday December 23rd, 2011). You now have another way to delete a remote

From its [EGit/New and Noteworthy/1.2](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/1.2#Delete_Branch_Command):

> In the commit graph area, there is a new context menu action "`Delete Branch`" allowing to delete a branch.
>   It will be enabled if a branch exists for the currently selected commit, which is not checked out.
>   If there is a single branch on this commit, which is not checked out, this action will delete this branch immediately.
>   If multiple such branches exist, a dialog will be shown asking which branches should be deleted.
>   If commits become unreachable on "Delete Branch" a confirmation dialog will be shown to prevent accidental unreachability of commits.

It remains to be tested if that option can delete a branch for a commit on a *remote* namespace (a commit part of a remote repo and fetched in your local repo).

Comment: In  Egit 1.3.0, this only deletes the remote tracking branch in the local repository, not the remote branch.

Comment: @tukushan: right. I have edited my answer to make the correct answer visible (and reference Michael Mior's answer)